# How to reference local import when patching - proper python testing structure

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching, python-mock

I have a Starlette app and I'm attempting to perform end to end testing on the entire application. A function defined in a.py is called by a function in b.py through a local import, and for testing purpose I would like to replace the function with a self defined function when testing.

Like others, I'm running into issues getting the path string to work. After looking at existing questions on stackoverflow, I think I'm supposed to be patching the reference in b.py, but run into the following error `AttributeError: <function b at 0x7f5298087af0> does not have the attribute 'a'`

Here's the relevant structure and code

```
    Project_folder
      - app
        - lib
          + __init__.py
          + a.py
          + b.py
        - handle
          + __init__.py
      - test
        + test.py
      + main.py
```

```
    #a.py
    def a(id):
      return stuff
```

```
    #b.py
    from .a import a
    def b():
      return a(some_stuff)
```

```
    #lib.__init__py
    from .a import a
    from .b import b
```

routes refers to an async function which calls b somewhere in the code

```
   #main.py
   from starlette.applications import Starlette
   from handle import routes

   app = Starlette(routes=routes)
```

My attempt at test.py

```
from starlette.testclient import TestClient
from main import app
import pytest
from mock import patch

client = TestClient(app)

def mock_a(id):
    return 'some value'

@patch('app.lib.b.a', new=mock_a)
def test_app(request):
    response = client.post('/route', request)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

I'm very new to mocks and patching, and would appreciate any advice on how I should be setting this up

Answer (score 0):

You import "a" and "b" as functions in **init**.py. So patch libs, not libs.a or libs.b. if you want to patch inside the module itself the take the imports out of **init**.py and the you can do something like this:

```
import libs
libs.b.b = libs.a.a
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I get what you mean. Is the above code something I should write in test.py? Would that change what is called by the client?

Comment: I tried `@patch('app.lib.a', mock_a)` but the original a() is called instead of mock_a.